# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am currently migrating my app from spring-mvc to spring boot.

I created pom.xml as shown below :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
</project>
```

I am unable to build the project. I am getting the below error :

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

I am using Apache Maven 3.3.9. My internet connectivity is fine so there should issues in downloading required jars then what is causing this error.
 Please help to resolve the issue

Comment: There could be a number of thing happening, a proxy in your environment for instance? Could you run `mvn help:effective-pom` and post the output?

Comment: Thanks @asettouf for the response. I ran mvn help:effective-pom command where my source code exists on my machine. I got build success. I resolved the issue by changing the version from 1.4.0.RELEASE to 1.5.2.RELEASE but I could not understand why mvn:help command did not fail for 1.4.0.RELEASE.